# Finding min of values across multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find min of values across columns in a pandas data frame where cols are ranged and split. For example, I have the dataframe in pandas as shown in the image.

[image: dataframe]

I am iterating over the dataframe for more logic and would like to get the min of values in columns between T3:T6 and T11:T14 in separate variables.

Tried `print(df.iloc[2,2:,2:4].min(axis=1))`

I expect 9 and 13  for Row1 when I iterate.

Comment: Guess this works now, now sure why it did not work earlier when I tried.`print(df.iloc[2,2:,2:4].min(axis=1))`

Answer (score 3):

create a simple dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

    A   B   C   D
0   2   0   5   1
1   9   7   5   5
2   5   5   3   0
3   0   6   3   8
4   4   4   4   0
5   8   2   1   4
6   4   1   1   8
7   6   5   2   9
8   2   4   3   0
9   4   7   1   8
```

use the min() function:

```
df.min()
```

result:

```
A    0
B    0
C    1
D    0
```

and if you wish to select specific columns, use the loc:

```
df.loc[:,'B':'C'].min()

B    0
C    1
```

**Bonus: Take pandas to another level - paint the minimum:**

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background-color : red; font-size: 16px' if v==x.min() else 'font-size: 16px' for _,v in enumerate(x) ],axis=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
print(df[['T'+str(x) for x in range(3,7)]].min(axis=1)]

print(df[['T'+str(x) for x in range(11,15)]].min(axis=1)]
```

should print the mins for all the rows of t3, t4, t5,16 and t11, t12, t13,14 separately

Comment: The issue I have is that I cannot access the columns by name as they are dynamic, how do I access by location instead.

Comment: Tried this `print(df[[df.columns[2,3,4]]].min(axis=1))` and got `IndexError: too many indices for array`

Comment: You can select columns by index using .loc[:,begin col:wnd col]. So replace the list comprehension in mine wutg df.loc[:,3:7].min(axis=1) https://thispointer.com/select-rows-columns-by-name-or-index-in-dataframe-using-loc-iloc-python-pandas/

Answer (score 0):

For test dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[x for x in range(100)], 'B': [x for x in range(10,110)], 'C' : [x for x in range(20,120)] })
```

Create a function that can be applied to each row to find the minimum:

```
def test(row):
   print(row[['A','B']].min())
```

Then use apply to run the function on each row:

```
df.apply(lambda row: test(row), axis=1)
```

This will print the minimum of whichever columns you put in the "test function"