# Flag the dataframe If a certain condition isn't met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df,  that shows certain values for a given day as well as a percent increase. I would like to somehow 'flag' my dataframe If the percentIncrease > or < a certain value.

```
   Date           Value  PercentIncrease
    
   10/08/2020     30     0%
   10/07/2020     30     0%
   10/06/2020     30     0%
   10/05/2020     30     0%
   10/04/2020     30     0%
```

Desired Output:

```
   Date           Value  PercentIncrease  Flag
    
   10/08/2020     6     0%
   10/07/2020     6     0%
   10/06/2020     6     0%
   10/05/2020     1000  16666%           OutofBounds
   10/04/2020     6     0%
```

This is what I am doing:

```
if  df[PercentIncrease'] > 10%():
          df['Flag'] = df['Flag'] = ['OutofBounds']
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `df.loc[df['PercentIncrease'] > '10%', 'Flag'] = 'OutofBounds'`.

Comment: Ok this works thank you- Is this better to use than If statement?

Comment: There is a catch though. You are comparing strings, so `'2%' > '10%'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the handy numpy 'where'.

such that:

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(df['PercentIncrease']>'10%','OutofBounds','')
```

this way, you can always use 2 values in the event of True or False. In your case I used OutofBounds and an empty string. Adjust to taste.

Comment: Hi @adhg, is there a way to add color to the dataframe? I am researching this

Comment: @Lynnette yes! you can. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485350/finding-min-of-values-across-multiple-columns-in-pandas/57487001#57487001)

Comment: Hi so I am thinking to incorporate this in the code above df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background-color : red; font-size: 16px' if PercentIncrease> '10%')    Would this be correct?

Comment: Need to know what is your desired result. Your code will not work because you didn't close the list-comprehension (the []) <-- this is where the loop happens. You also need to define what happens if not (meaning else). Make sense?

Comment: Ok- I will rework it - basically I am wanting the actual cell to flag red if the percent increase is > '10%'  - looking to see how to incorporate this by looking at your example

Comment: @Lynnette still struggling? let me know if so.

Comment: A little - I will create a new post @adhg